# Move Live USB To a new USB

Tags: linux, fat32

Ive got a Kali installation on a 8GB Usb and Ive ran out of space, it has 2 partitions, is there away that i could transfer the 8GB usb to a 32GB Usb and all the partitions.

Comment: Use DD to clone the partitions to the new device, you will have to extend the first partition, before you apply the second partition otherwise you will be unable to extend the first partition for obvious reasons.